# Get Object from ID in VisualForce rerendered page

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I am working with visualforce. Is there a way to get the fieldname from the **id** in the rerendered section of the visualforce page.
**{!$CurrentPage.parameters.cid}** gives me the id. Suppose that **cid** has the id of the contact object. How can i display certain fields of the contact object in the outputpanel. I tried the  but it gave whole detail. I only want certain fields.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are referencing [this](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_quick_start_query_params_getting.htm) documentation in your work. `$CurrentPage.parameters.parameter_name` is a way of getting query string parameters in Visuaforce and there is nothing to do with that for altering the fields you need in the `Contact` section. 
If you are using [`<apex:detail />`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_detail.htm) for the `Contact` section, what you can do is update your `Contact` object detail page layout as you need.